# CSS div container display: table with floating div

Tags: css, html

I have the following CSS DIV table grid that needs to have a DIV span over multiple DIVs

The issue I'm having seems to be related to the z-index between browsers. This code looks correct in Firefox but does not work in IE or Chrome which I've tested so far. I would like to know how to correctly float my DIV by CSS see the class ".blockdata" around my DIV which is set to display:table and will continue to allow overflow scrolling.

To see the difference, please check in Firefox then Chrome or IE.

You can view my example here at: http://jsfiddle.net/LjMhs/

Here's my CSS

```
/*column holder is not related to the grid - its used for the demo to force .table-inner to scroll */

.column-holder {
width:600px;    
}
.blockdata {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF 0%, #EEEEEE) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border: 1px solid #999999;
border-radius: 5px;
bottom: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;
color: #666666;
font-size: 12px;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 4px;
position:relative;
width:200px;
z-index:999;
}
.container {
display: table;
width:100%;
table-layout:fixed;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
.row {
display: table-row;
position:relative;
} 
.column {
display: table-cell;
border-color: #DDDDDD;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px ;
padding:5px;
width:120px;  
}
```

Here is the HTML table using DIVs

```
<div class="column-holder">

<div class="table-outer">
<div class="table-inner">


<!-- start div grid -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Column 0</div>
        <div class="column">Column 1</div>
        <div class="column">Column 2</div>
        <div class="column">Column 3</div>
        <div class="column">Column 4</div>
        <div class="column">Column 5</div>
        <div class="column">Column 6</div>
        <div class="column">Column 7</div>
        <div class="column">Column 8</div>
        <div class="column">Column 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Column 0</div>
        <div class="column">Column 1</div>
        <div class="column">Column 2</div>
        <div class="column">
        <div class="blockdata"> block data</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">Column 4</div>
        <div class="column">Column 5</div>
        <div class="column">Column 6</div>
        <div class="column">Column 7</div>
        <div class="column">Column 8</div>
        <div class="column">Column 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Column 0</div>
        <div class="column">Column 1</div>
        <div class="column">Column 2</div>
        <div class="column">Column 3</div>
        <div class="column">Column 4</div>
        <div class="column">Column 5</div>
        <div class="column">Column 6</div>
        <div class="column">Column 7</div>
        <div class="column">Column 8</div>
        <div class="column">Column 9</div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- end div grid -->

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with z-index. The only background property of .blockdata is:

`background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF 0%, #EEEEEE) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

So in the other browsers besides firefox the div is transparent :D

http://jsfiddle.net/eLz73/

Comment: You solution works, I was focused on the z-index which for some reason seemed like the issue. For other browser support on gradient I grabbed some CSS from http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ otherwise your fix is correct none -moz-linear-gradient support.

Updated revision: http://jsfiddle.net/LjMhs/1/

thanks for your quick response.